# How to insert js/jquery variable iside HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, var

Let's say that I have a variable,

```
var sticky_element = ".menu";
```

and the following line of code:

```
jQuery(sticky_element).wrapInner('<div class="menu-inner"></div>');
```

How can I replace the `menu` in `class="menu-inner"` with the variable `sticky_element`?

It seems following solution doesn't work. Why?

```
$(sticky_element).wrapInner('<div class="' + sticky_element + '-inner"></div>');
```

Comment: Jquery toggle will do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your variable declaration.

```
var sticky_element = ".menu";
```

is not the same as "menu", which you're trying to substitute with `sticky_element`. More explicitly,

```
sticky_element = ".menu" != "menu"
```

Omit the period from your variable string by defining

```
var sticky_element = "menu";
```

to find that this works.

Comment: That's it! I'm totally blind. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you change `sticky_element` from `".menu"` to `"menu"` it should work.

Comment: That's it! I'm totally blind. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

do it seperately, just save the current string into a variable like this:

```
var sticky_element = "menu"; // or '.menu'
var string = '<div class="' + sticky_element + '-inner"></div>';
jQuery(sticky_element).wrapInner(string);
```